# Version and/or license compatibility issues in Arcgis Products

Tags: licensing, arcobjects

I have developed a stand-alone application using Arcobjects SDK 10.2.2 for .NET . I can run this app. when arcgis Desktop 10.2.2 is already installed on any other computer, but not on a computer with 10.3 (or other versions) installed.

Is it possible to run an app. developed with 10.2.2 SDK and environment, on 10.3 installed platform ? and how? any document, link etc.?

Answer (score 0):

If the funcionality of ArcObjects API did not changed between 10.2.2 and 10.3 
versions, you should try to set attribute specific version to "false" in proprties window of referenced ArcObject libraries.